# Starting up an Intel SGX Enclave from a Java application

Tags: java, distributed-computing, sgx

Good evening, and thanks to everyone in advance.

I am currently working on My MsC Thesis, and for the proposed solution so far, I am to use an existing Java application (BFT-SMART, built with gradle version 7.3.3) and add it a layer of confidentiality using Intel SGX, with the objective of each replica containing its own Intel SGX enclave.

My problem however, is not being able to start an enclave from a Java application other than a given example.

The given example was all I found, and after some changes to its make File, I was able to successfully execute this simple Java application in Simulation Mode.
https://github.com/lishen-nt/sgx-language-adapter/

However, how do I adapt this to something different? The given code:

```
static {

        System.loadLibrary("Sgx");
    }

    /* Initialize the enclave */
    public native int jni_initialize_enclave();
```

Seems to only work with this given example, not working with other tests that I have personally been trying, with the project being unable to find said library. Is there a way to add Make File statements to a gradle build in order to link Intel SGX Libraries to the project?

Before considering adding Intel SGX to the aforementioned project, I was trying to build my own sample project to base myself off of, any tips on this?

I do apologize for the extremely ambiguous and open-ended question, I am just at a complete loss of where to begin looking for options or examples I could base myself off of.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying this old alternative (updated 4 years ago), I would try something newer, such as [Scone](https://sconedocs.github.io/Java/) or [SGX-LKL](https://github.com/lsds/sgx-lkl). I think it would be easier to get some help and get success with your project.